# Time difference in showed and actual webcam image

Tags: usb-camera, gscam, camera, webcam, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using a Pandaboard ES (ARM) and would like to synchronize a webcam (logitech c920) and a kinect. I want to grab single frames on a keypress and save pcd and jpg to disk.
Unfortunately is there a big lag in the webcam image which prevents me from a good result.
I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the lag of 2-5 sec of my webcam image (high resolution 2304 x 1536 / YUYV format)?
I tried usb_cam, uvc_camera (which is not working properly see this [topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/47209/uvc_camera-gets-a-terrible-image-and-usb_camera-doesnt-set-framerate/)) and the gscam package. But unfortunately all of them have a big lag between the showed and the actual image. I know that the frame rate will be low ,which is not a big problem, its more that the data is the wrong one when I want to save it.

**Edit 1:**
I looked for some unwanted queue as tfoote mentioned. The usb_cam package which seems for me to have a queue size of 1 and my subscriber uses queue size of 1, too. Could it be something else or am I wrong with the usb_cam?

**Edit 2:**
I realized that my camera offers MJPEG compression directly on the webcam. This works together with the usb_cam package and I get a much higher frame rate (around 10 fps without paralleled kinect capturing and around 5 with the kinect capturing). The lag now is around 1 second but the resolution is also lower with 1920x1080.
My first guess was that the camera has a internal memory which gets filled when the frames are not processed in time. Therefore I lowered the frame rate directly within the v4l2 driver to 5fps. This didn't brought better results also.

Would be great to get your thoughts about this problem?

**side note:** I get follwoing warning when using MJPEG compression

```
[swscaler @ 0x1c57aa0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to rgb24.
```

which is probably a ffmpeg related and issue and regarding to their forum shouldn't cause big problems. I tried to solve it by installing various versions of ffmpeg without success.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48762/time-difference-in-showed-and-actual-webcam-image/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

usb_cam driver does not buffer anything internally. Possible reasons for your lag are:

- Pandaboard and computer running e.g. image_view are not time synchronized
- Pandaboard can not serialize msgs fast enough
- Wireless connection does not offer enough bandwidth (we are experimenting with the arm processor on the tobi board and we do not get more than 300K of a bandwidth)

D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2013-01-09**:
Im not transfering anything and don't use image_view. I have a subscriber node which listens to both topics (webcam and kinect), synchronizes and saves them when I press a key.